# remove last STDOUT line in Python

Tags: python, stdout, command-prompt

I am trying to figure out how to suppress the display of user input on stdout.

`raw_input()` followed by any print statement preserves what the user typed in. `getpass()` does not show what the user typed, but it does preserve the "Password:" prompt.

To fix this, I would like to only remove the last line (which would remove the newline from the end of the line as well).

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You might be able to do what you want with [VT100 control codes](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm#cursor).

Something like this maybe:

```
CURSOR_UP_ONE = '\x1b[1A'
ERASE_LINE = '\x1b[2K'
print(CURSOR_UP_ONE + ERASE_LINE)
```

Comment: `print(CURSOR_UP_ONE + ERASE_LINE + CURSOR_UP_ONE)` did the trick for me.

Comment: Yes, this works for me. Thanks much! Unfortunately if the input to STDIN doesn't come from the keyboard then it ends up clearing too many lines though.

Comment: @javanix If on a UNIX machine (OSX or Linux) then you can use [`os.isatty`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.isatty) to check if `STDIN` is a console or not. Might be something similar for Windows but I don't know about it.

Comment: to erase the line `"\x1b[2K"` didn't work but `"\x1b[1M"` worked. After hours of searching, I could only find that command [here](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon#sequences)

Comment: @RuiBotelho It depends very much on the terminal type used. The Windows command prompt window, for example, is known for not handling VT100 escape sequences, or just a very limited subset of them. Any Linux or OSX terminal, on the other hand, should have very good implementation of them.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I found this sequence can only handle 23 lines. Would you please answer my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35267489/python-vt100-sequences-can-only-handle-23-lines-on-osxs-terminal

Comment: This works in linux bash, but isn't working on Windows' Powershell

Answer (score 3):

Give this a try:

```
CURSOR_UP = '\033[F'
ERASE_LINE = '\033[K'
print(CURSOR_UP + ERASE_LINE)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure if this works: maybe you could, just before calling `raw_input()`, replace `sys.stdout` with your self-defined file-like object which swallows the output. Right after that, you could set `sys.stdout` back to what it has been before.

Edit: looks like this approach does not work, because whatever the user types in stays on the screen.

Another option for console manipulation and direct keyboard control is [curses](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html).

Comment: I tried doing that but the problem is I believe the "display" of stdin must also be suppressed.

Comment: @javanix: you are right. I also just tried my suggestion. By default, whatever the user types, stays in the console.

Answer (score 1):

If what you're doing is reading a password, use `getpass`.  There are a lot of subtle gotchas involved in reading a *password* safely; it's not code you want to write yourself.

If you are doing something less security-critical, disabling terminal echo can be done with the [`termios`](http://docs.python.org/library/termios.html) module.  (I wish the example code there wasn't an incomplete, unsafe implementation of `getpass`, sigh.  But it does show you how to turn off terminal echo.)

If you're on Windows, there is an equivalent but I don't know what it is, and it may not be exposed in the Python standard library.

Comment: Nope, not doing anything security related - I just want my output suppressed.

Answer (score 1):

The following code, based on the Python docs, uses the `termios` module and seems to do what you want (although it is not as compact as VT100 control codes):

```
def getpass(prompt="Password: "):
    import termios, sys
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    old = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    new = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    new[3] = new[3] & ~termios.ECHO
    try:
        termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, new)
        passwd = raw_input(prompt)
        print '\r          \r',
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old)
    return passwd

p = getpass()
```

There are two tricky lines: one disables the echo, the other one erases your password prompt remaining at the first position of the line.