# how can avoid the output to look like a log(Python)

Tags: python, printing, replace, console

I'm writing a simple script for a slot machine game just after a tutorial on codeacademy.com
I would like to print things in the same place of the first print not everything under the previous. Is this possible?

In my script i print out a board like this:

```
slot = []

for row in range(9):
    slot.append(['[]'] * 9)

def print_slot(slot):
    for element in slot:
        print(" ".join(element))
print_slot(slot)
```

after this board i don't want  another board for every action
but i would like actions to happen in the board **or, even better** something like the output you get when you rerun the code.

how can achieve this? something different from print?
or maybe is the python console thet work like this, a complete program can be different. (real beginner here)

this is my output before the user input:

```
##- simple slotmachine -##
##- five identical win -##
##- u start with 100cr -##
[] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []
[] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []
[] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []
[] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []
[] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []
[] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []
[] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []
[] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []
[] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []
##- simple slotmachine -##
##- five identical win -##
##- space enter 2 play -##
```

here after the user input:

```
##- simple slotmachine -##
##- five identical win -##
##- u start with 100cr -##
[] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []
[] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []
[] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []
[] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []
[] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []
[] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []
[] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []
[] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []
[] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []
##- simple slotmachine -##
##- five identical win -##
##- space enter 2 play -## 
[] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []
[] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []
[] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []
[] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []
[] [] 0 4 5 4 5 [] []
[] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []
[] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []
[] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []
[] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []
```

as you can see the previous board is still visible, i would like to substitute a new board at every change.

Comment: can you show your output and desire output ?

Comment: 'I would like to print things in the same place of the first print not everything under the previous', please explain it more.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to clear python interpreter console?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517970/how-to-clear-python-interpreter-console)

Comment: ![this is what i get](http://i.xomf.com/yrnnw.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example how you can emulate a rewrite of an old line in `stdout` (actually you're going back to the start of the line using `\r` and **writing over** the old input):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import time

sys.stdout.write("This is in a line")
# force flush as stdout is flushed by default on '\n'
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(2)
# rewrite line and move to next
sys.stdout.write("\rThis is still in the same line\n")
```

You can use [these VT100 codes](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm#cursor) to overwrite previous lines as suggest in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586601/remove-last-stdout-line-in-python):

```
CURSOR_UP_ONE = '\x1b[1A'
ERASE_LINE = '\x1b[2K'

print "these"
print "are"
print "four"
print "lines"
time.sleep(2)
# go back two lines and overwrite with two new lines
sys.stdout.write(CURSOR_UP_ONE)
sys.stdout.write(CURSOR_UP_ONE)
print "five"
print "lines"
print "now"
```

Comment: i don't know if this will work too with a board made with a list and a loop, but hey thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Why not? If the board size is fixed you can make an `erase_board` function and call it before you re-draw the board. And always re-draw the board (instead of tracking small changes). You should also take a look at string formatting in python to better sync board cells' width. Good luck!