# How to avoid line break after user input in Python?

Tags: python, input, newline

How to change below code and remove unnecessary new line?

```
#"Please guess a number!"
choice = input ("Is it ")
print ("?")
```

> Is it 10
>
> ?

So that result will look like

> Is it 10?

Comment: Isn't the newline user input?

Comment: User input, as I know, by default ends with '\n'. I want to know is there any way to remove it

Comment: There is no newline here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean something like that?

```
choice = input ("enter somthing...")
print ("Is it "+str(choice)+"?")
```

Comment: this adds an extra line to stdout which i think is not what the question intended. A very similar solution is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586601/remove-last-stdout-line-in-python) that allows you to remove the line created by the input function

Answer (score 2):

To "remove" the newline in your code snippet you would need to send cursor control commands to move the cursor back to the previous line. Any concrete solution would depend on the terminal you're using. Strictly speaking, there are no unnecessary newlines in the sample above. The user provided the newline that follows 10, not Python. I suppose you could try to rewrite the input processor so that user input isn't echoed similar to `getpass.getpass()`.

Answer (score 2):

If someone looking for a solution, I found one-liner:

```
print('Is it ' + input('Please guess a number: ') + '?')
```

- Firstly, with above line user input requested as

  ```
  Please guess a number:
  ```
- Then user enter the value

  ```
  Please guess a number: 10
  ```
- After input confirmation (Pressing Enter) next line appears as

  ```
  Is it 10?
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If you need it to be longer then the above one you could drag it out.

Choice = input("Number:")
answer = "Is it %s ?" % choice
print(answer)

I like Shohams tho, more pythonic imho

Answer (score 0):

Very similar to the accepted answer in this question: [remove last STDOUT line in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586601/remove-last-stdout-line-in-python)

But here it is tailored to your solution. A little hackish admittedly, would be interested in a better way!

```
choice = input ("Is it ")
CURSOR_UP_ONE = '\x1b[1A'
ERASE_LINE = '\x1b[2K'
print CURSOR_UP_ONE + ERASE_LINE + 'Is it ' + str(choice) + '?'
```

Comment: NOTE: tested on osx successfully, don't have any other machines to try it on at the moment..

Comment: I'm afraid it's not working properly.
The output is:
<-[1A<-[2KIs it value?

Answer (score -2):

I do deep you cannot.Because if the procedure is "choice = input("Is it ")"，you must be to what end the enter,the line must be is new line.you can the change the express.
choice = input("Please input the number:")
print "Is it " + str(choice) + " ?"