# Real Time CountDown Timer In Python

Tags: python

As the title says, I wanna create a real-time countdown timer in python

So far, I have tried this

```
import time
def countdown(t):
    print('Countdown : {}s'.format(t))
    time.sleep(t)
```

But this let the app sleep for the 't' seconds but the seconds in the line don't update themselves

```
countdown(10)
```

Desired Output :

```
Duration : 10s
```

After 1 second, it should be

```
Duration : 9s
```

Yeah, the problem is the previous line `Duration : 10s` which I have to erase. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a lot of help from this thread : [remove last STDOUT line in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586601/remove-last-stdout-line-in-python)

```
import time

def countdown(t):
    real = t
    while t > 0:
        CURSOR_UP = '\033[F'
        ERASE_LINE = '\033[K'
        if t == real:
            print(ERASE_LINE + 'Duration : {}s'.format(t))
        else:
            print(CURSOR_UP + ERASE_LINE + 'Duration : {}s'.format(t))
        time.sleep(1)
        t -= 1

countdown(4)
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply do this:

```
import time
import sys

def countdown(t):
    while t > 0:
        sys.stdout.write('\rDuration : {}s'.format(t))
        t -= 1
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(1)

countdown(10)
```

Import `sys` and use the `sys.stdout.write` instead of print and flush() the output before *printing* the next output.

Note: Use carriage return,"\r" before the string instead of adding a newline.

Comment: When using a number 10 or higher, a trailing zero remains once the counter reaches number 9 and below.  For example, `countdown(11)` will look like this: 11 --> 10 --> 90 --> 80 --> 70 --> etc.