# Only updating the values in loop

Tags: python

I'm building a time count-downter. I just wanted to update the 'time' everytime instead of printing the whole thing again and again. Loops prints the same thing again and again. Like, suppose I want to print 1 to 10. The output will be
1
2
3
4
5 ... But I want 
1 (and then the 1 will be removed)
2 ( it will be removed and the next one will be printed)

Comment: It is not very clear to me what you want to achieve. Please provide the current attempt, the output, and the requested output.

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Real Time CountDown Timer In Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41347676/real-time-countdown-timer-in-python)

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: You can check my code in https://trinket.io/python/c642117f02

Answer (score 0):

`\r` prints a carriage return first, so `remain_time` is printed on top of the previous line.

```
import sys                #Added
import time              

while True:
  now= time.time()
  current_time= (time.asctime())
  current_hour= current_time[11:13]
  current_minute= current_time[14:16]
  current_second= current_time[17:19]
  remain_hour= 23 - int(current_hour)
  remain_minute= 60 - int(current_minute)
  remain_second= 60 - int(current_second)

  remain_time= "%sh %sm and %ss remaining" %(str(remain_hour),str(remain_minute), str(remain_second))
  sys.stdout.write('\r'+remain_time)                #Changed
  #print('\r'+remain_time,end="")      #Alternatively you can also use this
  time.sleep(1)                                     #Changed
```