# How to clear the last printed line in python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.6

I want to make a timer so like this:

```
import time
print ("Loading program...")
time.sleep(1)
```

now i want to delete the

```
Loading program...
```

I only want to delete the latest line nothing else.Im running python 3.6, Thanks for any help.
I have tried method that have been linked to me but they all have not worked i just want a simple code to remove the last line printed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586601/remove-last-stdout-line-in-python

Comment: I have tried the methods you guys have linked and none of then worked i just want a simple code that deletes the last line printed.

Comment: The simplest answers are the ones that have already been linked to.  What happened when you tried the answer [linked here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12586667/7203016)?